# Tapping on the app icon does not display the notification in the app

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using the **Event source-based notifications in hybrid applications** sample from https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/notifications/push-notifications-hybrid-applications/event-source-based-notifications

When I receive a push notification and I tap on the app icon instead of tapping the notification in the notification bar, the notification isn't pushed and still appearing on the notification bar. Only if I tap on the notification bar, even if the app is open, the notification is pushed and is deleted from the notification bar.

There are no problems if the app is open when I receive the notification.

How I can force the notification to be pushed when I tap on the app icon rather than tapping the notification in the notification bar?

MobileFirst 7.0.0

Android Environment

Comment: How can we tell you this w/out looking at your implementation? Are you following a sample? your own app? What is the environment? Provide something to work with...

Comment: I used the "Event source-based notifications in hybrid applications" sample

Comment: Did you alter it in any way?

Comment: No, I've only added gcm key. I'm using the AVD with the google api 4.4.2

Comment: Can you test with a physical device instead?

Comment: I tested the sample in a Samsung S4, and the behavior is the same, if I open the app from its icon instead of from the notification on the notification bar, the callback "pushNotificationReceived" isn't invoked until you click on the notification bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have indeed reproduced this. It appears to be a regression.

After a push is received and you then tap either the incoming notification in the notifications bar or the app icon

1. the app is supposed to launch
2. you are then prompted to login
3. push support etc is checked for, and finally
4. if there's a notification in the queue then it is supposed to be displayed (the `pushNotificationReceived` function is supposed to be called). This is not happening when tapping on the app icon

If you are an IBM customer or business partner I suggest for you to open a PMR (support ticket). This is going to be investigated by the development team...

Comment: In my case it fails with ad 1. My app isn't launched when I tap on the notification.